# is it possible to use (string, int) in the same method to get a return (string) and return (int)?

Tags: java, string, methods, int, return

```
           import java.util.Scanner;
           public class Return {

                  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                  public static void main(String[] args) {
                          inputTest();

                             }
                  public static void inputTest(){
                      System.out.println("From Digit (9635)");
                      System.out.print("Enter a Digit: ");
                      int number = input.nextInt();
                      System.out.println(Digit(number));

                             }

                 public static int Digit(int number) {
                      if (number == 1) {
                        System.out.print("The 4th number in the argument is =\t"); 
                        return 5; 
                    } else if (number == 2) {     
                        System.out.print("The 3rd number in the argument is =\t");  
                        return 3;
                    } else if (number == 3) {
                            System.out.print("The 2nd number in the argument is =\t"); 
                        return 6;
                    } else if (number == 4) {
                        System.out.print("The 1st number in the argument is =\t"); 
                        return 9;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Sorry! That's not part of the argument =\t"); 
                            **return 0;**
                     }
                 }
           }
```

/* is it possible to use (string, int) in the same method to get a 
return (string) and return (int)??
i want to that return 0(int) to become return none(String) */

Comment: A Java method can only have one return value.

Comment: Questions and challenges like this cause me to think about how Ruby, Perl, Lua, Python, etc allow returning a list of items from a function.  And a generalized return a list of objects from a Java function would solve this quite nicely, but cause more work processing the results.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two return values from the same method, but you can:

1. Return `String.valueOf(int)`, or
2. Return a custom object that contains both a `String` and an `int`

Comment: +1 for "return a tuple containing both int and string", although I would suggest returning a heterogenous list of object ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1) Use a return object with 2 properties such as Apache Pair.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

2) Pass in an object (e.g., a StringBuilder) and have that object store one of your return values (e.g., StringBuilder.append).

Comment: I'm not sure your second option will work the way you want it to in Java. Have you tested it?

Comment: You're right, I Java doesn't pass anything by reference.  I got it mixed up w/ C++.  I'll modify my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. The method:

```
public static int Digit(int number){
 ...
}
```

has to return an integer as specified.

But you can change it to a String after the value is returned (i.e. in your inputTest  method)

```
public static void inputTest(){
    System.out.println("From Digit (9635)");
    System.out.print("Enter a Digit: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int digit = Digit(number);
    if(digit!=0)
        System.out.println(digit);
    else
        System.out.println("none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to compromise on the return type, you could return a HashMap of the values you require